# How do I compare a variable to a string in python?

Tags: python, string

Im new to this so Im sorry if this isn't the best way to ask the question...

here is the code -

```
import sys

print("What is ur name?")
name = sys.stdin.readline()

answer = "jack"

if name is answer :
    print("ur awesome")
exit();
```

right now when I run it in cmd I don't get anything printed even though 
I input - jack? thank you in advance

Comment: Use `==` instead of `is`.

Comment: Be careful with `sys.stdin.readline()`. It will preserve newline. So if you enter `jack`, it will actually be `jack\n`. So, `answer == "jack"` will be False when it should really be true. You are better off using `input()` instead.

Comment: With `sys.stdin.readline()`, you want `answer==name.strip()` otherwise use `input()`

Comment: Also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988017/string-comparison-in-python-is-vs) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345202/python-getting-user-input).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, replace `is` with `==`. `is` checks whether the two underlying strings are the same entity (in memory) whereas `==` just wants to check if they have the same value.

Because the source of "jack" is coming from two sources (one from the user, another hard-coded by you) they are two seperate objects.

As @dawg mentioned you also have to use the `.strip()` to get rid of the newline when using `sys.stdin.readline()` for input. The best way to read input is to use the `input()` method in python3, or `raw_input()` in python2.

`name = input('What is your name?\n')`

Comment: You need `.strip()` since the `sys.stdin.readline()` includes the `\n`

Comment: I like the explanation, but offering a solution would make the answer even better :)

Answer (score 4):

Use `==` for string comparison. Also, `readline()` will include the newline at the end of the string. You can strip it with e.g.

```
name = name.strip()
```

Alternatively, you can use `raw_input()` (`input()` in python 3) instead of `readline()`, as it will not include the newline to begin with.

```
name = raw_input("What is your name?\n")
```

It's helpful to be able to print a string to see if it has any extra whitespace, e.g.

```
print("name: [%s]\n" % name)
```

Comment: Great, but please add reference to `input()`