# What did I do wrong

Tags: python-3.x

---

```
import sys

super_heroes = {'Iron Man' : 'Tony Stark',
            'Superman' : 'Clark Kent',
            'Batman' : 'Bruce Wayne',
            }

print ('Who is your favorite Superhero?')

name = sys.stdin.readline()

print ('Do you know that his real name is', super_heroes.get(name))
```

---

I'm doing a simple code here that should read an input in a dictionary and print it out after a string of letters, but when ran it prints out

"
Who is your favorite Superhero?

**Iron Man**

Do you know that his real name is **None**
"

Even Though the input is in my dictionary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345202/getting-user-input)

Comment: Do you have allergy with python's `input()` method?

Answer (score 2):

Your input is having a newline at the end of the line.

I have tried it online REPL. [Check it](https://repl.it/repls/AuthorizedMajorCustomers)

try following to resolve it.

```
name = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
```

After stripping [Check here](https://repl.it/repls/AuthorizedMajorCustomers)

Answer (score 1):

`sys.stdin.readline()` returns the input value including the newline character, which is not what you expect. You should replace `sys.stdin.readline()` with `input()` or `raw_input()`, which are really more pythonic ways to get input values from the user, without including the newline character.
`raw_input()` is preferable to ensure that the returned value is of string type.

To go a little bit further, you can then add a test `if name in super_heroes:` to perform specific actions when the favorite superhero name is not in your dictionary (instead of printing `None`). Here is an example:

```
super_heroes = {'Iron Man' : 'Tony Stark',
                'Superman' : 'Clark Kent',
                'Batman' : 'Bruce Wayne',
               }

print ('Who is your favorite Superhero?')

name = raw_input()

if name in super_heroes:
    print ('Do you know that his real name is', super_heroes[name], '?')
else:
    print ('I do not know this superhero...')
```

Answer (score 0):

`sys.std.readline()` appends a line break at the end of user input you may want to replace it before getting your Super Hero:

```
name = name.replace('\n','')
```