# How to parse arguments to a function in Python?

Tags: python, arguments

I've been trying to understand tutorials on how to parse arguments in Python using argparse. Is this how I would pass a command line input so I can run a function?

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='A test')
parser.add_argument("--a", default=1, help="Test variable")

args = parser.parse_args()

def foo():
    command_line_argument = args.a
    bar = 2*args.a
    print(bar)
    return

if "__name__" == "__main__" 
    try:
        while True:
        foo()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('User has exited the program')
```

Comment: It's `if __name__ == '__main__':`, you've got it the wrong way around.

Comment: The parsing should be done inside the `if` block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `while True` looks odd to me -- are you asking the reader to keep submitting inputs until they CTRL+C ? Because if so, argparse is the wrong thing to use: see [Getting user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345202/getting-user-input)

If you intend a single argument then I'd move the parser stuff inside main, which is what gets executed when the script is run as a program as opposed to being imported.

Also, I'd pass a parameter to `foo` rather than the args block.

Lastly, I guess you're expecting to receive a number so you need `type=int` or similar.

```
import argparse


def foo(a):
    bar = 2*a
    print(bar)
    return

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    try:
        # set it up
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='A test')
        parser.add_argument("--a", type=int, default=1, help="Test variable")

        # get it
        args = parser.parse_args()
        a = args.a

        # use it
        foo(a)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('User has exited the program')
```

So:

```
$ python foo.py --a 1
2
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the confusing code I was trying to come up with some example code to illustrate what I want. This is exactly what I want!

Answer (score 0):

below is in working state

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='A test')
parser.add_argument("--a", default=1, help="Test variable", type=int)

args = parser.parse_args()

def foo():
    command_line_argument = args.a
    bar = 2*args.a
    print(bar)
    return


if  __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        while True:
            foo()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('User has exited the program')
```

if you run `python your-filename.py --a=2` it will print `4` until you stop the execution.