# Add inputs to GEKKO

Tags: python, gekko

I need some help with GEKKO

I want the equation be set by an imput insted of the in the code
Its not an int input since it has a "x" in it and string wont work since it has numbers in it.

```
from gekko import GEKKO

m = GEKKO()
x = m.Var()

m.Obj(x**2)

m.Equation(3*x+5==4*x)

m.solve(disp=False)
print(x.value)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3345202/getting-user-input)

Answer (score 1):

You can input the equation as a string (as `seqn`). You can convert the string to an expression with the `eval()` function. This evaluates the expression as if you had it in the code.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
seqn = '3*x+5==4*x' # input as string
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
x = m.Var()
m.Obj(x**2)
m.Equation(eval(seqn))
m.solve(disp=False)
print(x.value)
```

If the form of the equation is always the same, you can add parameter inputs such as `p=m.Param()` and then set `p.value=6`. This inserts a different number in your equation such as `3*x+p==(p-1)*x` when you need to solve the same equations multiple times but with different inputs.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
x = m.Var()
p = m.Param(5)
m.Obj(x**2)
m.Equation(3*x+p==(p-1)*x)
m.solve(disp=False)
print('Solution with p=5: ' + str(x.value))

p.value=6
m.solve(disp=False)
print('Solution with p=6: ' + str(x.value))
```

You can also add an input as a float or int as `p=6` but this only works to set the value once because `gekko` writes the model file with this constant. You can see the model file `gk_model0.apm` by opening the run folder with `m.open_folder()`.

```
Model
Variables
    v1 = 0
End Variables
Equations
    (((3)*(v1))+5)=((4)*(v1))
    minimize ((v1)^(2))
End Equations
End Model
```

This APMonitor model file is compiled to byte-code each time there is a `solve` command. Advanced users can add lines to this file with `m.Raw()` but I don't recommend it unless there is a good understanding of the internal methods of APMonitor.