# How do I use a input in my python program

Tags: python

sorry for the question title, I don't know how to word it.
I coded a program that guessed your password by randomly generating passwords until it gets a match. you could only change the password by editing the code, I wanted to upgrade it and make it so you can type the password in the console and it guesses it but when I tried it had a bug. This is what happened:
this is my code

```
letter=("a""b""c""1""2""3")
import random
print ("Please type a 6 character password with a, b, c, 1, 2, 3, you may use characters more than once.")
password = input
spam=(random.choice(letter)+""+random.choice(letter)+""+random.choice(letter)+""+random.choice(letter)+random.choice(letter)+""+random.choice(letter))
found = spam == password
if not found:
  print(spam)
elif found:
 print ("I found your password: " + spam)
```

but when I start the code this is what happens

```
Please type a 6 character password with a, b, c, 1, 2, 3, you may use characters more than once.
c1aca2
```

instead of just showing the instructions it shows a password combination.
another issue it that when I type in the password and click enter I get a syntax error

Comment: password = input() just add the brackets in

Comment: I am not really familiar with the way you write python, but you might want to include a while loop in your code and also learn about permutations.

Comment: [Getting user input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3345202/2745495)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line

```py
password = input
```

to

```py
password = input()
```

If you don't include the parentheses you are assigning password to the function `input`. Instead you have to call the function `input()` for password to be assigned of what's returned by `input()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following function.

```
import random

def guessPassword():
    password = input("Please type a 6 character password with a, b, c, 1, 2, 3, you may use characters more than once.")
    spam = (random.choice(letter)+""+random.choice(letter)+""+random.choice(letter)+""+random.choice(letter)+random.choice(letter)+""+random.choice(letter))
    i = 1   
    while(spam != password):
        spam = (random.choice(letter)+""+random.choice(letter)+""+random.choice(letter)+""+random.choice(letter)+random.choice(letter)+""+random.choice(letter))    
        i += 1
    print("I found your password at %d times" % (i))
    print("Your password is: %s" % (spam))
```